# Adding An AlertView At viewWillAppear, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, alert, terminate

I am attempting to show an alert view as soon as the view appears (without using a button). In viewcontroller.m I have:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle: @"User Information" message: @"Hello"
                              delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Continue", nil];

    [alert show];

    [alert release];
}
```

and in viewcontroller.h I have:

```
IBOutlet UIView *alert;
```

I haven't done anything to my .xib file.

When run on the simulator I get the following in console:

2009-11-30 23:41:36.079 BatteryApp[867:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "BatteryAppViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Any ideas where I have gone wrong, something to do with my xib?

Edit // I connect alert to a new view in my xib, still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the two core animations (the one for viewing the current view, and the one for showing the alert ) overlap.  You need to separate these two animation moves, by following this workaround:

1. Have the alert code be in `viewDidAppear`, rather than `viewWillAppear`
2. Call `[alert performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]`.  This ensures that the alert occurs after finishing the current animation.

You may need to be careful about releasing `alert` quite yet.  If I were you, I would have a separate method (e.g. showHelloAlert), and then call it from viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated {
  [self performSelector:@selector(showHello) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, error gone, and alert is displaying... but 3 times! It displays then automatically disappears. It then re-appears, but requires you to dismiss it before appearing once more!

Comment: I suspect that you are calling `viewDidAppear:` explicitly multiple times, or that the delegate method calls `showHello` accidentally.  You would need to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the alert in viewDidAppear.

Also, what is the iboutlet for? Try taking the whole thing out.

Answer (score 0):

Open your xib file in Interface Builder, and control drag from the file owner (which should be of class `BatteryAppViewController`) to your view (not the alert) and select view from the menu that pops up. The log indicates you haven't made this outlet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect UIAlerts up in Interface Builder. Alerts do not have customizable nibs so you can't load them up in interface builder. You need to remove the:

```
IBOutlet UIView *alert;
```

...completely.

The error message says that you have no view defined for your view controller. You need to set that up in Interface Builder.